# Property is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. VUE.JS

Tags: vue.js

**This is my Task.vue file**

My template:

```
    <template>
        <table :id="id" class="task_box" :style="{background:toto}">
    </template>
```

**Exporting**

```
<script>
    export default {
      name: "task",
      props: {
            id: {
                type: Number
            },
            emergency: {
                type: String,
                name: "Urgence"
            },
      },   
      computed: {
              toto() {
          return "white";
            }

    }
    };
</script>
```

**This is my Tasklist.vue**

```
<template>
      <task v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id" 
        :emergengy="task.emergency">
        </task>
    </template>

<script>
import Task from "./Task.vue";

export default {
  name: "tasklist",
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: [
        {
          id: 4}]}}};
```

**This is the error I'm getting**

**[Vue warn]: Property or method "toto" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.**

Comment: Is that "Exporting" section surrounded by opening and closing `<script>` `</script>` tags in the `Task.vue` file immediately following the `<tempale></template>` section?

Comment: Yup that's exact.

Comment: Then you should not be getting that error. It should actually be telling you that `isDisplayed` is not defined. Are you trying to access the `toto` variable in the template of any other component?

Comment: the isDisplayed is a prop I have but I forgot to cut it. toto is only in the running component called task.vue: I'm using toto for a switch case that's pretty much it. I'm looking to pass a type to the function so it determines which case I am running.

Comment: Here's is your example running without issues https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kz9woRkbGgzO3U4Dd-k

Comment: Well, when I'm looking at your link and I inspect it I can see in the console that you have the exact same issue as I have :/

Comment: https://ibb.co/hHnxa6 there you can see what I mean

Comment: You must have caught me mid-edit those errors were for the `foo` and `bar` properties I hadn't defined in the parent scope. Check again. No errors related to `toto`.

Comment: Got it to work in the end it was an indent issue. Thanks once again for your time I'll delete it soon.